# Ускорение кода для скачивания данных из Telegram и сохранения их в CSV файл с дозаписью

Tags: python, строки, файлы, csv, telethon

Реализовал следующую функцию, которую хотелось бы ускорить как можно сильнее:

```
async def async_update_database(self, source_id: str, source_hash: str, message_id_1: str, message_id_n: str, file: str):

        entity = types.InputPeerChannel(int(source_id), int(source_hash))

        n_messages = 0
        n_comments = 0

        with open(file, 'a', encoding = "utf-8") as fout:
            for message_id in range(int(message_id_1), int(message_id_n) + 1):
                message = await self.client.get_messages(entity, ids = message_id)
                if message == None or message.message == "" or message.replies == None or message.replies.replies == 0:
                    continue

                fout.write("M," + str(int(message.date.timestamp())) + ',' + str(message_id) + ',' + repr(message.message) + '\n')
                n_messages += 1

                async for comment in self.client.iter_messages(entity, reply_to = message_id):
                    if isinstance(comment.sender, types.User) and not comment.sender.bot:
                        fout.write("C," + str(int(comment.date.timestamp())) + ',' + str(comment.sender.id) + ',' + repr(comment.message) + '\n')
                        n_comments += 1

        return (str(n_messages) + " " + str(n_comments))
```

Функция вызывается из внешнего кода, запрашивает данные постов и комментариев к ним из Telegram каналов, скачивает их и сохраняет в формате CSV в файл. Вызовов много, поэтому запись в файл установлена на режим добавления в конец. Объемы скачивания: один вызов данной функции может скачивать 10'000 постов, по 1000 комментариев в каждом, т.е. в файл записывается 10'000'000 строк.

Что можно сделать с этим кодом? Я не знаток Python, могу иметь какие-то глупые ошибки здесь. Из того, что мне кажется не очень оптимальным: 1) Эффективно ли работает дозапись в конец файла в таком виде? 2) Нет ли проблем с асинхронными вызовами? 3) Правильно ли я использую функции из библиотеки Telethon?